# Ошибка при ./configure пакета

Tags: linux, debian, makefile, package

Собираю из исходников libsndfile.
Выполняю ./configure и в ходе процесса получаю следующее сообщение

```
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG:: команда не найдена
```

Не могу разобраться, в чем причина.

Comment: *"Не могу разобраться"* -- а пробовали? И наличие `pkg-config` проверяли, и наличие/путь к  `pkg.m4`, как это гугл в первых же строчках советует?

Comment: Естественно, я сначала искал подобную проблему в поисковиках   find /usr -name "pkg.m4"  
`/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4`  
`aclocal --print-ac-dir`  
/usr/local/share/aclocal  
`|/ Имя            Версия       Архитектура  Описание  
+++-==============-============-============-=================================  
ii  pkg-config     0.28-1       i386         manage compile and link flags for`

Comment: Возьмите, например, сорцы сборки от Debian (*rules*) или RedHat (*libsndfile.spec*) да и посмотрите как их собирают, но вообще изначально непонятно, зачем это вам? Пакет на 99.9% есть в дистрибутиве.

Comment: У меня установлен debian из образа net-install, я начал собирать mednafen, он попросил эту либу, начал собирать либу - она ругается на сабж. Как в сказке про репку. Не понимаю, чем мне помогут сорцы сборки?  И я пробовал ставить сначала apt-get'ом, так что это тот 0,01%

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил:

```
# apt-get install libsndfile-dev
```

Господа, спасибо за просвящение меня :-)